# Pure JavaScript on screen keyboard issue

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have an on-screen keyboard and 5 input boxes. My problem is when I focus on an input box and input something, nothing will happen. I want to add input every time I focus on an input box.

Here's my simple code. This code only works for 1 input field. I want to make this work for 5 or 4  input fields.

```
function writeKey(key){
  if(key){
    if(key == "Enter"){
      key = "10";
     } else if(key == "tab"){
      document.getElementById("feld1").value += "\t ";
    } else if(key=="backspace"){
      document.getElementById("feld1").value=document.getElementById("feld1").value.slice(0,-1);
    } else if(key==" "){
      document.getElementById("feld1").value += " ";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("feld1").value += String.fromCharCode(key);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [document.activeElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.activeElement#Browser_compatibility) which points to currently focused element.

You can rewrite your code like this using it:

```
function writeKey(key){
  var el = document.activeElement;
  if(key){
    if(key == "Enter"){
      key = "10";
     } else if(key == "tab"){
      el.value += "\t ";
    } else if(key=="backspace"){
      el.value = el.value.slice(0,-1);
    } else if(key==" "){
      el.value += " ";
    } else {
      el.value += String.fromCharCode(key);
    }
  }
}
```

Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/XBppR/3/)

Please note that you should run writeKey not onclick but onmousedown. Otherwise focus will be already moved from an input. Demo reflects that.

Here is its html code:

```
<div onmousedown="writeKey('a');return false">Click key</div>
<input type="text" />
<input type="text" />
<input type="text" />
```

Also, take a look at `return false;` after writeKey is called. It will prevent default browser action and clicking on a key you will not loose a focus from your input. Without it you will need to set focus on an element after each key press.

Comment: but i am using simple on screen keyboard...this would work?please bear with me im just a beginner..thanks..

Comment: Hm. Now I'm confused. What is on screen keyboard in your case? And why do you need to write a values into it like that? I thought you have a keyboard built with JS/HTML. If you are using windows onscreen keyboard or like those on iPad and similar than why do you need that code at all?

Comment: If you are using some on screen keyboard built in to windows or some mobile device, than it should work just like any regular hardware keyboard and this code looks to be a nonsense at all.

Comment: im making sms interface with a keypad...so basically i should have 3 input fields for ("sender's name" "phone number" and "message")...so inorder to put something to a field i should focus each field..thats my problem...thanks...

Comment: Well, I shown to you how that could be done. I see an example of a key in your comment below. Let me update demo to work with keys like you have.

Comment: See updated demo: http://jsfiddle.net/XBppR/5/ It is using code of your `q` button and document.activeElement. with mousedown event and return false (that is important! see my answer why)

Comment: Oh. Please, read what people tell to you. Being a beginner does not mean that you should not read explanations. Take a look at this updated demo: http://jsfiddle.net/XBppR/11/

Comment: Besides, using those multiple if statements in your writeKey function is terrible. Switch is much cleaner (just simpler to support such code in future). In the latest demo I've used switch in your writeKey function. Suppose it is obvious that it is much easier to read than numerous `if`s in your  initial code. It is important to have code which is easy to read. Just as advice  for future :)

Comment: oppps!there's a problem again...when i press the CAPS LOCK AND SHIFT the form disppears.. :(

Comment: See this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/XBppR/14/ and read comments I left in showTab function. Also, pleas note that I've added an id="keyboard" to a div with class="keyboard" to make it work

Comment: how ca i validate form using my on screen keyboard?i have a code but only works in hardware keyboard...please help?

Comment: here.. http://jsfiddle.net/XBppR/15/ ive added the js code in the <script> and i used onkeypress in the input with name="web"..thanks..

Comment: Hm. As it is done now, no keypress event will be fired. You can generate it, but I think you should better test that in your writeKey function. See updated demo: http://jsfiddle.net/XBppR/16/ (writeKey function updated)

Comment: how to enable/disable a div tag and all elements inside it when a button is click?

Comment: @ChristianBusaco Disable div tag? There is no such feature in HTML. You need to remove event handler and "disable" it that way. When you enable them, you will need to assign all events again. Another option is to add some global variable which will reflect a state of divs. And in event handler you can check that variable and do nothing if it says that div is disabled.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you actually call the `writeKey` method. You could rewrite your code like this:

```
function writeKey(key, fieldId){
  if(key){
    if(key == "Enter"){
      key = "10";
     } else if(key == "tab"){
      document.getElementById(fieldId).value += "\t ";
    } else if(key=="backspace"){
      document.getElementById(fieldId).value =
          document.getElementById(fieldId).value.slice(0,-1);
    } else if(key==" "){
      document.getElementById(fieldId).value += " ";
    } else {
      document.getElementById(fieldId).value += String.fromCharCode(key);
    }
  }
}
```

Or you could pass the filed itself:

```
function writeKey(key, field) {
    ...
    field.value += "\t";
    ...
}
```

Comment: my code in the html area is for example for letter 'q'

<div class="button black" onclick="writeKey('113')" >&#113;</div>

how will i able to include the field id when i have 5 field id's?

Comment: @ChristianBusaco Why do you need to pass a code if you can simply pass a symbol? Instead of `writeKey('113')` you can do `writeKey('q')`